# git doesn't work. I get "'git' is not recognized as ..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I am trying to run this line out of http://docs.heroku.com/quickstart

```
git init
```

But I get [image]

How do I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install git on windows first, and then use the GIT bash shell. Here is the site for GIT on windows http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/

Just install that, open GIT Bash, navigate back to that directory and run that command again.

Comment: O so I have to do that in GIT Bash?

Comment: Either do it in GIT bash, or like codethis said, add GIT to your PATH variable and you can do it from command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you did all the prerequisites on that page.

Did you install git? http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/

If so, make sure the location of the executable is in your PATH variable.

This site may help too:
http://kylecordes.com/2008/git-windows-go

Answer (score 1):

i will suggest you to use [tortoisegit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/downloads/list) , a git for window. But yet , develop rails in window is suffering , why don't you just dual boot your computer to linux and window ?